# Xamarin.ios can't deploy to physical device directly

Tags: xcode, xamarin, deployment, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I created a free provisioning profile on xcode and i also created a unique bundle identifier , after that i connected the mac(*virtualbox i used 2 laptops running on window*s) to windows visual studio , in visual studio .iOS i also set the identifier same as i created in xcode and change the configuration to debug and platform to iphone ,selected the  manual provisioning ,
all is working and good to go , i plugged my iphone to the laptop in mac once it recognized my phone i started to build it.

and the result is

**Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped**

**Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped**

it doesn't install it to my iphone i don't know what's wrong.

Comment: The iPhone needs to be connected to your Mac, *not* the Windows PC running Visual Studio

Comment: yes it's connected to mac

Comment: i editted it @SushiHangover

Answer (score 1):

Below are the possible cases,

1. If you are using VisualStudio and trying to deploy your application in mac/iphonedevice through hosting, then the installed xamarin version should same in both VisualStudio and Mac. Otherwise this issue may occur.
2. Check whether the certificate is created and applied to your iphone device properly. You can check this by opening XCode in your mac.